# Combining JavaScript Objects into One

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called "Colorbox" (jQuery plugin) that takes a number of parameters like so:

```
$(this).colorbox({
    width : "500px",
    height : "500px"
});
```

I have several different types of "this", though, each with their own properties. Like so:

```
var Type = {
  video: {
    width : "500px",
    height : "500px"
  },
  gallery: {
    width : "1065px",
    height : "600px"
  }
}
```

Beyond that, I have other behaviors, logic, and a 'default' group of settings (which get overwritten by more specific ones). What I'm trying to do is push all the appropriate settings, from multiple objects, into a single Object so I can just call:

```
$(this).colorbox(Settings);
```

How would I transfer an unknown group of properties and their values (for example "width" and "height") from something like Type.video into Settings? The goal is to be able to call Settings.height and get back the value I pushed in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Please see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33572520/2934015 for caveats and an alternate solution.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Take a look at the JQuery [extend](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method.  It can merge two objects together and all their properties.

From JQuery's example page:

```
var settings = { validate: false, limit: 5, name: "foo" };
var options = { validate: true, name: "bar" };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);
```

Now settings contains the merged settings and options objects.

Comment: This looks perfect! I guess I thought there would be a built-in javascript method for this, but Extend seems to do exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: This seems useful to the OP but technically it's not what the question asks for. The OP didn't mentioned he wanted to use jQuery for that... Just plain JavaScript.

Comment: The OP is writing a jQuery plugin sp it would seem silly to give a more complicated solution when it would make most sense to use a jQuery function inside of a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 13):

JavaScript have a simple native function to merge object. which is Object.assign() introduced in ES6.

```
  // creating two JavaScript objects
    var x = { a: true };var y = { b: false}; // merging two objects with JavaScript native function
    var obj = Object.assign(x,y);
    //result
    Console.log(obj); // output is { a: true, b: false }
```

for more information about javascript merging object please check at [merge JavaScript objects](http://authortuts.com/how-to-merge-javascript-objects/) with examples.

Comment: Upvoted. I had to upgrade node, because of the "undefined is not a function" error - even when running node with the --harmony flag...

Comment: This does not work with nested layers in objects, it only works at the top level

Comment: For the sake of completeness: The target of the merge is the first argument to `Object.assign`, ie. `x` in the sample code  is mutated. See [here(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for details.

Answer (score 12):

A non-jQuery solution is:

```
YOUROBJ.vars = {
    vars1: {
        vars1_1: 'an object which will overwrite',
        vars1_2: 'an object which will be added'
    }
};

YOUROBJ.vars2 = (!YOUROBJ.vars) ? {} : YOUROBJ.vars;

YOUROBJ.vars = {
    vars1: {
        vars1_1: 'an object which will be overwritten',
        vars1_3: 'an object which will remain'
    }
};

YOUROBJ.extend = function(obj, defaults) {
    for (var i in defaults) {
        if (!obj[i]) {
            obj[i] = defaults[i];
        } else {
            YOUROBJ.extend(obj[i], defaults[i]);
        }
    }
};
YOUROBJ.extend(YOUROBJ.vars, YOUROBJ.vars2);
delete YOUROBJ.vars2;
```

This is useful if you wish to add a variable to a general functions object before it has been loaded and created.

This also enables the second YOUROBJ.vars to act as the default setting,.

Comment: What does "FC" refer to?

Comment: My guess is they actually are using this code in their code base calling it `FC`, and changed it to `YOUROBJ` to answer the question and just missed a spot.

Comment: Correct. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using jQuery you should checkout the [$.extend](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend#deeptargetobject1objectN) function.

You could try something like this:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function(options){
  settings = $.extend(true, {default_values: "foo"}, options);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have also created a "merge" function in Javascript to use for my general purposes:

```
if (typeof Object.merge !== 'function') {
    Object.merge = function (o1, o2) { // Function to merge all of the properties from one object into another
        for(var i in o2) { o1[i] = o2[i]; }
        return o1;
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var eDiv = document.createElement("div");
var eHeader = Object.merge(eDiv.cloneNode(false), {className: "header", onclick: function(){ alert("Click!"); }});
```

It's quicker and dirtier (shallow copy), but it does what I need it to do.

Comment: Warning: extending the Object prototype like that is unadvisable and generally dangerous. 

Pretty good writeup on the dangers of this and when/how you can get away with it here http://sugarjs.com/native and a great talk on the subject here http://blip.tv/jsconf/jsconf2011-andrew-dupont-everything-is-permitted-extending-built-ins-5211542

Comment: @timoxley: If you look closely, it isn't actually modifying the Object prototype.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your question very well but i think you should use the $.extend function:

```
Settings=$.extend(Settings, Type.video);
```

in this way Settings will get Type.video properties

Comment: Fair enough about the question. Thanks for the example, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply first level merging (appending keys from second object to first one):

```javascript
var mergeObjects = function (originalObject, objectToAppend) {
    for (var item in objectToAppend) {
        if (objectToAppend.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            originalObject[item] = objectToAppend[item];
        }
    }
};
```

`originalObject` must be non-null!

Comment: In what case would hasOwnProperty trigger a false result in the check? Is there additional items that the foreach loop will extract out of the object?

Comment: @Prusprus *["The use of hasOwnProperty() prevents the loop from enumerating over any inherited properties on the object"](http://brianflove.com/2013/09/05/javascripts-hasownproperty-method/)*

Comment: That's a good reference, thanks for that. So I guess I'm a little confused as to how an array (say in the example given thru your URL) can have inherited properties, if it's just an array?

Comment: @Prusprus Every array inherits properties added to [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype): *"`Array` instances inherit from `Array.prototype`. As with all constructors, you can change the constructor's prototype object to make changes to all `Array` instances."*