# Native way to merge objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, prototype

Javascript's Object doesn't have any native merge operation.  If you have two objects, say

```
{a:1, b:2}
{c:3, d:4}
```

And want to get

```
{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}
```

As far as I know, you have to iterate through the objects.  That is to say that you decide on either a merge left or merge right strategy and then you do something like (simplified)

```
for (key in object2) {
  object1[key] = object2[key];
}
```

This is fine.  However, Javascript has the `call` and `prototype` feature.  For instance, turning `arguments` into an `Array` can be done with

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`

This approach exploits existing native code, and so therefore is less susceptible to programmer folly and should run faster than a non-native implementation.

#### The question

Is there a trick to use this prototype/call pattern on perhaps the `Attribute` or `Node` traversal features of the DOM, or perhaps some of the generic `String` functions in order to do a native object merge?

The code would look something like this:

`var merged = somethingrandom.obscuremethod.call(object1, object2)`

And as a result, you'd get a native merge without a traversal.

#### A possible, sub-optimal solution

If you could use the `constructor` property of an `Object` and then coerce one object to have a constructor of another object and then run `new` over the composite object, you may get a merge for free.  But I don't have a firm grasp of the full implications of the `constructor` feature in javascript to make this call.

#### Lemma

The same question holds true for `Arrays`.  A common problem is to take, say 7 arrays of numbers, then try to find out the intersection of those arrays. That is to say, which numbers exist in all 7 arrays.

You could concat them together, then do a sort, and then do a traversal, surely.  But it would be nice if there is a generic intersect tucked away somewhere that we can coerce an array to doing natively.

Any thoughts?

edit:

#### Getting half way there

For the array problem, you could do the following:

array.concat(a, b, c).sort().join(':') and then use some tricky `RegExp` capture and repeat patterns in order to traverse.  RegExp implementations, if you don't know, run on a very simple stack-based virtual machine.  When you initialize your regular expression that's really a program that gets compiled (RegExp.compile is a deprecated JS method).  Then the native runs over the string in a blisteringly fast way.  Perhaps you could exploit that for membership thresholds and get better performance...

It still doesn't go all the way though.

Comment: This is an awesome question. Alas i doubt the answer is anything but a big fat no... but here's to hoping, it would sure come in handy :)

Comment: Awesome question--I also think the answer is no, but the relevant places to look are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2 here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods and here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf (starting at section 15.4.4)

Comment: I also hope there is a way to do this  ;)  Sadly, if there is, I doubt it's cross-browser.

Comment: CSS Classes are a merge.  If we can exploit this, then we have it.

Comment: It's worth noting that I searched through v8 and spidermonkey for merge like programming patterns and tried to traverse up the stack to see what was calling them ... nothing yet.

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1).slice(0,-1) + ',' + JSON.stringify(obj2).slice(1)) is about 3.5 times slower then the traditional merge

Comment: Why on earth is there not something like `Object.merge` in ES6. :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using ES6 (ES2015) you can use **Object.assign** method:

```
var x = {a:1, b:2};
var y = {c:3, d:4};
var z = Object.assign({},x,y);
```

Using ES7 (ES2016, Chrome 60+ or Babel) you can use **Object spread operator**:

```
var x = {a:1, b:2};
var y = {c:3, d:4}; 
var z = {...x, ...y};
```

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this because the answer to this question has changed in the past 11 years.

Comment: To merge an object with array inside, we need a little help yet:
https://runkit.com/lagden/647fcc64b0b29a0008097df0

Answer (score 24):

My answer to this will be disappointing, but still:

**no**

The reason for this is simple: Mr Resig's implementation of merge (or "extend" as it's called for objects) in jQuery is doing a loop, just like the one in your question. You can look at it [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bbdfbb4ee859fe9319b348d88120ddc2c9efbd63/src/core.js#L124). And I dare say that if John Resig hasn't found a clever build-in way to do it, then the mere mortals of stackoverflow won't either :)

Comment: I'm just full of off topic comments today. :o) Just FYI, you can click a line number at github to create a direct url to that line. Shift-click to highlight a range.

Comment: Jquery extend works for functions and objects; I would be happy with a shallow merge that works just for strings or numbers.  It's a smaller, and thus different problem domain.

Comment: Two very useful comments, that's not something I see every day :)

Comment: Function instanceof Object === true; extend works for all objects

Answer (score 3):

The million dollar question! I've tried doing this numerous ways, and the loop way described above always seemed the dirtiest. ES6's `Object.setPrototypeOf()` allows you to delegate a "property override" object to a "default properties" object, pretty much accomplishing what you're trying to do, but using `Object.setPrototypeOf()` has some serious implications, like disabling the browser's compiler optimizations for the whole script.

Also, in both the loop solution and the `Object.setPrototypeOf()` solution, you are left with a situation where the "property override" object can mutate the "default properties" object:

```
defaultObj = {
    a: [1, 2]
}
...
overrideObj = {
    b: 3
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(overrideObj, defaultObj);
console.log(overrideObj); // {a: [1, 2], b: 3}
// Great!
...
overrideObj.a.push(4);
console.log(defaultObj); // {a: [1, 2, 4]}
// Uh-oh.
```

You might think this is not a problem, but let's say you're using this object as configuration for a 3rd party lib. You are now handing the control of your default object and everything referenced in it to the 3rd party lib.

A better solution might be to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to copy and combine the objects. Here's a Gist with the example:
https://gist.github.com/spikesagal/6f7822466887f19b9c65

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, no. Also, you'll want to write your merge method like this:

```
function mergeInto(o1, o2) {
  if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
    return o1;

  for (var key in o2)
    if (o2.hasOwnProperty(key))
      o1[key] = o2[key];

  return o1;
}
```

Comment: A little off topic, but you can test for `null` or `undefined` at the same time if you use `==` instead of `===`, as in `if(o1==null || o2==null) return o1;` This is because `null==undefined`.

Comment: @patrick dw: true. For some reason I thought that `0 == null` would be true, but I just tried it and it's not. Thanks.

Comment: Actually this is wrong ... it doesn't check for types.  You should do
if (o1.prototype !== Object.prototype || o2.prototype !== Object.prototype)
otherwise you could get numbers or strings passed in.

Comment: ^^ my comment above has incorrect code.  Please excuse me. ^^  You still need to check for the type though.

Comment: Well, you could add a type check, but I'm not sure it should be this method's job to make sure you didn't pass in a `Date` or something. If you did want to, though, you should do `Object.prototype.toString.call(o1) == "[object Object]"`.

Comment: That's an argument of design truly.  MDC's suggested alternatives to newer JS features usually include very strong type checking as scaffolding. e.g. Array.indexof: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf . I would certainly argue that the type checking is the professional proper way to do things; but at the same time; don't think the programmer should expect to be formally notified for screwing up like that and view it as an unnecessary added cost.  Mixed; truly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following using native JS 1.7, without the need of a framework. See example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdgrimes/HgKeB/) (example only intended for simple objects - not complex nested objects)

```
var obj1 = {a: "a", b: "b"};
var obj2 = {c: "c", d: "d"};

// The magic: ugly but works perfectly
var value = (JSON.stringify(obj1).concat(JSON.stringify(obj2))).replace("}{", ",");

document.getElementById("lbl1").setAttribute("value", value);

// back to object
var obj3 = JSON.parse(value);
document.getElementById("lbl2").setAttribute("value", obj3.a + " " + obj3.b + " " + obj3.c + " " + obj3.d);
```

Comment: Yes, ugly! :-) I do recommend everyone use jQuery, but if you are tempted to use the above, change it not to choke on `"}{"` appearing inside the JSON strings:
`var obj1Json = JSON.stringify(obj1);`
`var value = (obj1Json.substr(0,obj1Json.length-1).concat(JSON.stringify(obj2).substr(1)));`

Comment: Sorry, that should have been:
`var value = (obj1Json.substr(0,obj1Json.length-1) + "," + JSON.stringify(obj2).substr(1);`

Comment: Ron, you're a real Honey Badger! Awesome native approach... (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the spread operator (`...`) and the `Object.assign` approach to get a good solution for the case where you have a bunch of objects in an array and want to merge them all into one super object.

```
const obj1 = {a:1, b:2}
const obj2 = {c:3, d:4}
const objArr = [obj1, obj2]
const mergedObj = Object.assign({}, ...objArr)

> { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No native ways in ECMA-Script, use:

```
function merge(o1,o2) {
 if (typeof(o1)!=='object') o1={};
 if (typeof(o2)!=='object') o2={};
 for (var k in o2) {
 if (o1[k]!==undefined)
  alert ('Collision Error'); // TODO
 else
   o1[k]=o2[k];
 }
 return o1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Below I've included a deep-merge function I wrote. It will not deep-merge Arrays, only Objects. It will take two objects, and return a third, new object.

```
var merge = function(o1, o2) {
    var o_new = {};
    for(p in o1) {
        if(o1[p]) {
            if(typeof o1[p] == 'object' && !(o1[p] instanceof Array) && o2.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                o_new[p] = merge(o1[p], o2[p]);
            }
            else {
                o_new[p] = o1[p];
            }
        }
    }
    for(p in o2) {
        if(typeof o2[p] == 'object' && !(o2[p] instanceof Array) && o1.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            o_new[p] = merge(o1[p], o2[p]);
        }
        else {
            o_new[p] = o2[p];
        }
    }
    return o_new;
}
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers on an almost 6 year old question.

Comment: Neither does that commentary ^