# Joining two JavaScript arrays on specific keys (like mySQL join)

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, merge

I am trying to 'join' two arrays on a key value.

The first array:

```
    "matches": [
           {
           "name": 33,
           "home_team": 4,
           "away_team": 1,
           "home_result": 3,
           "away_result": 0
           },
           {
             ...
           }
           ]
```

The second array:

```
  "teams": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Russia"
        },
        {
          ...
        }
]
```

When looping through matches, I would like to join the home_team id with the respective team id and display teams[i].name instead of the id. The same for away_team.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
var mymatches = [];
for (i=0;i<matches.length;i++) {
   var h = matches[i].home_team;
   var a = matches[i].away_team;
    var mymatch = {
      name: matches[i].name,
      home_team: teams[h].name,
      away_team: teams[a].name

    };
   mymatches.push(mymatch);

}
```

When loggin variables a and h, the correct number is being output, however it is not being accepted in the [] part, which I find strange as it works with [i] in a for loop...

The full data is from a JSON file available below. I know that the matches array is nested within a "groups" object, however I was able to 'unnest' the "matches" arrays:

https://github.com/lsv/fifa-worldcup-2018/blob/master/data.json

Comment: Take a look at this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593515/analog-to-sql-join-for-javascript-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593515/analog-to-sql-join-for-javascript-objects)

Comment: Desired output:    "matches": [
           {
           "name": 33,
           "home_team": Uruguay,
           "away_team": Russia,
           "home_result": 3,
           "away_result": 0
           },

Comment: You should do some changes to your code first you should add `Number` function to parse to integer in this line `var h = matches[i].home_team;` and `var a = matches[i].away_team;` you use `var h = Number(matches[i].home_team);` and the same for the other to get an integer variable and not string, second thing is that when you create `mymatch` variable you should add quoutes to `name` and `home_team` and `away_team` like `'name'` and `'home_team'` and `'away_team'`.