# How can I inner join with two object arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, inner-join, ecmascript-5

I need inner join with two array in javascript like this:

```js
    
    array1 = 
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tufan"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Batuhan"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Hasan"
      }
    ]
    
    array2 = 
    [
      {
        "name": "yyy",
        "externalid": "1",
        "value": "Asd"
      },
      {
        "name": "aaaa"
        "externalid": "2",
        "value": "ttt"
      }
    ]
    
    expectedArray = 
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tufan",
        "externalid": "1",
        "value": "Asd"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Batuhan",
        "externalid": "2",
        "value": "ttt"
      }
    ]
```

rules:

1. on: **array2.externalid = array1.id**
2. select: **array1.id, array1.name, array2.externalid, array2.value**

My approach:

```
array1.filter(e => array2.some(f => f.externalid == e.id));
// I need help for continue
```

How can I make this?

*Doesn't matter information: I use ES5 and pure javascript*

Comment: Maybe try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593515/analog-to-sql-join-for-javascript-objects , mix it with Object.assign()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Analog to SQL 'JOIN' for Javascript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593515/analog-to-sql-join-for-javascript-objects)

Comment: That links not same this

Comment: Your code is using es6 syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const res = array2.map((item) => {
  const related = array1.find((el) => el.id == item.externalid);
  return { ...item, ...related };
});
```

Using a map to loop over the array2 and a find to get the array1 relative.

Comment: ... operator not supported es5 :(

Comment: @TufyDuck what browsers are your building this for? Why don't you use Babel if you're concerned?