# Add nested json object item to another json item

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

**I want to add two nested objects in JSON in typescript.**

In JSON given below I want to add second JSON's activityLogs item in first JSON's activityLogs.

**JSON1:**

```
[{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":
    [{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:40:18"},
     {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:38:18"},
     {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:37:18"}]
}]
```

**JSON2:**

```
[{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":
    [{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:46:18"},
    {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:43:18"}]
}]
```

**Result:**

```
[{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":
    [{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:46:18"},
    {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:43:18"},
     {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:40:18"},
    {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:38:18"},
    {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:37:18"}]
}]
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Native way to merge objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740806/native-way-to-merge-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: try to use `concat` with specific condition ,if not you can use lodash use merge.a[0].activityLogs = a[0].activityLogs.concat(b[0].activityLogs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `push()` with the spread operator or `concat` and reassign:

```js
var JSON1 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":[{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:40:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:38:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:37:18"}]}]
var JSON2 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":[{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:46:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:43:18"}]}]

JSON1[0].activityLogs.push(...JSON2[0].activityLogs)

console.log(JSON1)
```

This assumes that your json arrays contain just the one top-level object. If that's not the case you need to add more details about how the two arrays are synchronized (for example will `vehicleno` be the same in both?).

As an example, if the `vehicleno` is a unique identifier in both arrays you could create a lookup of the `JSON1` values and the use that to push into the appropriate arrays. This will update `JSON1` in place even if it contains multiple vehicles:

```js
var JSON1 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":[{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:40:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:38:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:37:18"}]}]
var JSON2 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":[{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:46:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:43:18"}]}]

let lookup = JSON1.reduce((lookup, obj) => {
  lookup[obj.vehicleno] = obj
  return lookup
}, {})

JSON2.forEach(obj => lookup[obj.vehicleno].activityLogs.push(...obj.activityLogs))
console.log(JSON1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, this is working for me. But it is pushing data in bottom but I want this in top.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I used unshift instead of push and it is adding on first index. It solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatination array method.

```
let json1 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":[{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:40:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:38:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:37:18"}]}];

let json2 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":[{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:46:18"},{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:43:18"}]}]


let result = json1[0].activityLogs.concat(json2[0].activityLogs);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @bear-nithi Its concat but removed the vehicleno and device_code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to `concat` the `activityLogs`:

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "vehicleno": "SV028",
  "devicE_CODE": "8505",
  "activityLogs": [{
      "gpsdate": "01/03/2019",
      "gpstime": "13:40:18"
    },
    {
      "gpsdate": "01/03/2019",
      "gpstime": "13:38:18"
    },
    {
      "gpsdate": "01/03/2019",
      "gpstime": "13:37:18"
    }
  ]
}];
var arr2 = [{
  "vehicleno": "SV028",
  "devicE_CODE": "8505",
  "activityLogs": [{
      "gpsdate": "01/03/2019",
      "gpstime": "13:46:18"
    },
    {
      "gpsdate": "01/03/2019",
      "gpstime": "13:43:18"
    }
  ]
}];
var arr3 = arr1[0].activityLogs.concat(arr2[0].activityLogs);
console.log(arr3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

Note this will only work if you only have one object in the top-level array.

Comment: Its concat but removed the vehicleno and device_code

Answer (score 0):

```
result = json1;
/// result = Object.assign({}, json1); if you don't want to mutate the original json1
result.forEach(elem1 => elem1.activityLogs
    .concat(json2.find(elem2 => elem2.vehicleno === elem1.vehicleno).activityLogs));
```

Concat the activityLogs of the second array item to the first array item by finding the matching element by `vehicleno`..

Answer (score 0):

```
var json1 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":
    [{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:40:18"},
     {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:38:18"},
     {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:37:18"}]
},{"vehicleno":"SV02","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":
    [{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:40:18"},
     {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:38:18"},
     {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:37:18"}]
}]


var json2 = [{"vehicleno":"SV028","devicE_CODE":"8505","activityLogs":
    [{"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:46:18"},
    {"gpsdate":"01/03/2019","gpstime":"13:43:18"}]
}];

var jsonCont = json1.concat(json2);

var result = Object.values(jsonCont.reduce((acc, o)=>{
    if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(o['vehicleno'])) {
        acc[o['vehicleno']] = Object.assign({}, o);
    } else {
        acc[o['vehicleno']]['activityLogs'] = acc[o['vehicleno']]['activityLogs'].concat(o['activityLogs']);
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```