# Add Javascript Object into another Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

Given

```
options = {
 underscored: true
}

products = {
 foo: bar
}
```

I'd like to get

```
products = {
 underscored: true
 foo: bar
}
```

Is it possible to push an object into another object in Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334660/combining-javascript-objects-into-one

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**ES5**

```
<script>
function mix(source, target) {
   for(var key in source) {
     if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        target[key] = source[key];
     }
   }

}

  mix(options, products);
</script>
```

**ES6 - this will mutate objectToMergeTo**

```
const combinedObject = Object.assign(objectToMergeTo, source1, source2)
```

**ES7 (syntax beauty with spread operator)** -
this version however creates a new instance, you can't add into an object with spread operator.

```
const combined = { ...source1, ...source2 }
```

Comment: +1 for `hasOwnProperty()`! This is the proper way to iterate over an objects properties.

Comment: Thanks you've been a great help!

Comment: Peter, that ES7 syntax seems to just create a third object containing the two objects as a whole, rather than just their properties

Comment: At least in Node.js

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
for(var key in options) {
    products[key] = options[key];
}
```

That would effectively combine the two objects' variables.

Comment: This is missing a `hasOwnProperty` check and will produce unexpected results, depending on the two objects. Besides, it will create a global variable `key`, which is bad. Always use the `var` keyword!

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
    underscored: true
};
var products = {
    foo: 'bar'
};
products.underscored = options.underscored;
alert(products.underscored+":"+products.foo);
```

put quotes around the 'bar' to make it actually have a value, semi-colons and var on the objects, but you get the point.

EDIT: also worth noting;

```
products.options = options;
alert(products.options.underscored);//alerts true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery.extend(products,options). jQuery.extend combines two objects, over rides the matching element values in the target object and returns resulting object. For more info :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/