# Adding objects to an object property which is an object itself with object assign

Tags: javascript

so say I have this:

```
const mainObject = {
  prop1: false,
  prop2: {} or []
}

const minorObject = { name: "name", address: "address" }
const minorObject2 = {name: "name2", address: "address2" }
```

how do add them one at time to `mainObject.prop2` without mutating `mainObject` with `Object.assign`, if it is not possible then how can it be done with ES6 spread?

Comment: What is it you are not wanting to mutate?

Comment: do you regard `mainObject.prop2 = minorObject;` as a mutation ??

Comment: i basically want to add a new copy of `mainObject` with the content of `minorObject` first. so on and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to keep the main reference **immutable** you need to work with [`shallow copies`](http://blog.soulserv.net/understanding-object-cloning-in-javascript-part-i/), similar to what happen when you work with primitives.

An example with Strings (when literally declared they are treated as primitives):

```js
var a = 'Hello';

var b = a; 
b += ' World';

console.log({a, b});
```

As you can see, mutating `b` the variable `a` remains immutable... this because [`primitives are passed by value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

Because `Object` is not a *primitive* it is `passed by reference` and the above example becomes:

```js
var a = { prop: 'Hello' };
var b = a;
b.prop += ' World';

console.log({a, b});
```

> how do add them one at time to mainObject.prop2 without mutating mainObject ...?

```js
var a = { prop: 'Hello' }
var minorA = { prop1: ' World' };
var minorB = { prop2: ' Moon' };

var b = Object.assign({}, a); //create a shallow copy
Object.assign(b, minorA, minorB)

// because you can pass as many params you want, you can simplify the previous code in this way:

var b = Object.assign({}, a, minorA, minorB);
```

> how can it be done with ES6 spread?
>   The `Object spread operator`, that is in `esnext`, you can use it with babel and [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

```
var b = {...a};
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign will mutate the object passed as the first argument, so if you want to combine the properties of two objects without mutating either, simply wrap one Object.assign inside another.

```
Object.assign(Object.assign({},mainObject),minorObject)
```

Answer (score -1):

[How to push elements of an object into another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949552/how-to-push-elements-of-an-object-into-another-object)

[Add Javascript Object into another Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843884/add-javascript-object-into-another-javascript-object)

google keyword search = 
add an object to another object

plenty of more examples out there and ways of going about it.