# Combine Javascript Objects?

Tags: javascript

Are these just objects, not arrays? How can I combine them into a new variable?

```
var common_options = {
    'city': 'Baltimore',
    'state': 'MD'
}
var other_options = {
   'name': 'bob',
   'job': 'cook'
}
```

I tried this with no luck

```
var new_options = $.merge(common_options, new_options)
```

and

```
var new_options = common_options.concat(new_options)
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334660/combining-javascript-objects-into-one

Comment: These are under the assumption you're using jQuery