# How to bind two object to one in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a query filter in my code, I want to pass these two queries as one like this:

```
 case1 
  con = {'eq':['case1':dosome]}
 case2
  con = {'eq':['case1':dosome]}
```

I need to bind these two at the end like this

```
{'eq':['case1':dosome],'eq':['case2':dosome]}
```

the key eq should remain same.

Comment: I don't think having two items with the same key is a very good idea. How are you going to tell them apart?

Comment: the result does not work with the same key.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, it's just that you can't. One or the other will get overriden

Comment: I hope this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334660/combining-javascript-objects-into-one

Comment: btw, its not valid syntax.

Comment: Or use one key and combine both values in one single value such as `{'eq': ['case1':dosome, 'case2': dosome]}`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an object with two properties like

```
{ eq: { case1: dosome, case2: dosome } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an array of objects:

```
var your_array = new Array();
var con1 = {'eq':{'case1':dosome}}
your_array.push(con1)
var con2 = {'eq':{'case2':dosome}}
your_array.push(con2)
```

You can then use the methods for accessing parts of the array -> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp

Comment: This will give error. Have a look at my answer.. Look at ['case1':dosome]. By the way, nice way +1

Comment: oh sorry, why not make that an object as well?

Comment: But also why do you need the `'eq'` identifier if it is always the same?

Comment: HI.I need to build my object from {'eq':['case1':dosome]} Not {'eq':{'case1':dosome}}

Comment: Pretty sure that is just incorrect syntax in javascript, it will never work.  Using `[]` defines an array, but inside the array you are using `:` to define a `key:value` pair I imagine, but this is not how arrays are used.  It is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Use merge() function. Also this will give error: **['case1':dosome]**. Try this

```
<script>
var obj1 = {'eq':{'case1':dosome}};
var obj2 = {'eq':{'case2':dosome}}
var merge = obj1.merge(obj2);
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{ eq: [
  { condition: 'case1', action: doSome } , 
  { condition: 'case2', action : doSomeOther }
]}
```